# Trouble retrieving logged in user info from database with PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query and display user information from the database such as name and email. I've spent a couple days on this and read some similar threads here but have had no luck.

If I use the following query I can get what I want about a specific user and display it accordingly.

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM users where username = 'blim'";
```

Now I want to run the same query but replace 'blim' with ($_SESSION["username"]) I get an error.

```
$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM users where username = ($_SESSION["username"])";
```

The reason why I thought this would work is because by using

`<?php echo ($_SESSION["username"]); ?>`

I am able to display a greeting specif to the user logged in so I thought I could compare that to rows in the database to retrieve information from specific columns.

Comment: try this way  `$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM users where username = '".$_SESSION["username"]."'";`

Comment: The error you are getting is telling you what's the problem. Probably you get `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in `. @MyNameIs comment should work.

Comment: If you "get an error", why don't you share it with us?

Comment: You could use `$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM users where username = '{$_SESSION['username']}";`, which is only a slightly shorter version fo MyNameIs's comment. Array inside a string needs to be enclosed in `{}`. Also, don't forget the `'` you had around `'blim'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading the username from session into its own variable, then use that variable in the query.

$username = $_SESSION["username"];

$sql = "SELECT firstname, lastname, email FROM users where username = $username";

Comment: Thanks! Yea this works. So simple yet I needed to add another step. I think I was even onto that and didn't try it for some reason.